# Wordpress get posted in category permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So each post it will be posted in one category, and for each post I want to get the posted in category permalink, only the URL **without** markup.
How can I do that?

//Explained again

Well the post is posted in a category, right? Well I need to show that category, but not the name of the category, the url for that category.

Comment: Sorry, I may not be firing on all cylinders yet today. But -- when you say the "posted in category permalink", what exactly do you mean? Do you have a custom permalink structure set up? Can you give us an example of the URL you want to end up with, and how it relates to your chosen WordPress permalink setting?

Comment: Well the post is posted in a category, right? Well I need to show that category, but not the name of the category, the url for that category. Did you get it now :-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)(), which will return an array of objects, one for each category. In your case, you'll get an array containing one object back, because you only have one category. Then use [get_category_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)() to  turn the ID of the category into a URL.

So, if you're in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), I would do something like this (NB: untested!)

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$url = get_category_link($categories[0]->cat_ID);
```

Obviously, you'll want to make sure this doesn't fall on its backside if there are no categories assigned, for example.

This is similar to what WordPress does if you include a category in your permalink structure -- it will get the category with the lowest numeric ID and use that in the permalink.

Answer (score 0):

No need to even place the anchor tag just place the following code, it will echo the URL and NAME as a permalink. It's build in already in WordPress.

```
<?php the_category(', ') ?>
```